# Extending a raster with specific slope

Tags: qgis, raster, extents

I have a raster layer which i want to extend. The problem is that i want to extend it with specific ratio of vertical/horizontal (1:2). What is the best way to do that in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please try to explain what you have, what you want, and **what you have tried**.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. What I actually want to do is to extend the raster, not to convert the cells. What is appearing in that picture with blue colour is flood extend. What I want to do next is to extend it sideways but with specific slope. For example if the cell nearmost the orange polygon has depth 1 meter i want to be extended proportionally for 2 meters horrizontally. I hope that the question was made more clear this time. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

**If** I understand your request, you might look at the GRASS GIS module `r.grow.distance` ([module manual page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.grow.distance.html)). This module takes a raster as input, with features and NULL cells surrounding. THen it creates two new expanded rasters: for each cell, the distance to a non-null cell, and the value of the closed non-null cell. You would need to first extract your flood areas (leaving the orange areas as NULL). Then use the "value" output raster to determine which cells have value less than two times the "distance" output raster. This will require an "if..." clause in a map calculator expression.